# What is the default instance context mode?

Tags: wcf

When I do not specify `InstanceContextMode` in the service, what's the default instance mode?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's PerSession

[Link to MSDN doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode)

Comment: Link is dead, if you still know where to find it I'd like to read it.

Comment: @Grummle Weird... why did ms remove it? It's still in Google's cache: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Yyw4N7BfwP4J:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode(v%3Dvs.110).aspx+&cd=3&hl=fr&ct=clnk&gl=nl

Comment: In case the doc gets removed from cache: Use the InstanceContextMode property to specify when new service objects are created. Because the service object is not directly connected to the communicating channel, the lifetime of the service objects is independent of the lifetime of the channel between a client and the service application. The default value, PerSession, instructs the service application to create a new service object when a new communication session is established between a client and the service application. Subsequent calls in the same session are handled by the same object.

Comment: Link is back from the dead :)

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is that the default Instancing mode is `PerSession`

Provided:

- The Session Type you are using supports sessions
- See [Binding type session support] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/system-provided-bindings).
- If the channel does not create a session the behavior is as if it were `PerCall`.
- The Service contract allows sessions - default is "Allowed"

Here is a Microsoft provided sample with the default imperatively configured in the code.
[Default behavior sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/default-service-behavior)

```
[ServiceBehavior(  
AutomaticSessionShutdown=true,  
ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Single,  
InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerSession,  
IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=false,  
UseSynchronizationContext=true,  
ValidateMustUnderstand=true)]
public class CalculatorService : ICalculator { ... }
```

I found reading about session in this Microsoft article ( [Using Sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/using-sessions) ) particularly enlightening in understanding how Sessions is opened and closed and how this relates to Instancing and Concurrency.

By default the WCF client will create a new session, which will create a server instance, all calls for the duration of the session is called a conversation and is served by a single instance (Instancing) of the server with a single thread (Concurrency) dedicated to that session/client/conversation.

> If you use the default instancing behavior in WCF, all calls between a WCF client object are handled by the same service instance. Therefore, at the application level, you can think of a session as enabling application behavior similar to local call behavior. For example, when you create a local object:
>
> A constructor is called.
>
> All subsequent calls made to the WCF client object reference are processed by the same object instance.
>
> A destructor is called when the object reference is destroyed.
>
> Sessions enable a similar behavior between clients and services as long as the default service instance behavior is used.

Hope this helps someone as it took me a while to find the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not all bindings support `PerSession` mode like `basicHttpBinding` that supports `Percall` mode by default.

Comment: I confirm, generally persession mode is the default mode however some bindings don 't support persession mode like basicHttpBinding : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330030/does-wcf-basichttpbinding-support-persession

Comment: does basicHttpBinding only support Percall or other modes are available?