# Does Wcf basicHttpBinding support PerSession?

Tags: wcf

Does the `basicHttpBinding` in WCF support `PerSession` value in service behavior ?

Where can i find a table which summarize all the information for each binding and its options ? ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, basicHttpBinding does not support this due to the connectionless nature of the HTTP protocol. You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://codeidol.com/csharp/wcf/Instance-Management/Per-Session-Services/):

> For example, the BasicHttpBinding can never have a transport-level
>   session due to the connectionless nature of the HTTP protocol. The
>   WSHttpBinding without security and without reliable messaging will
>   also not maintain a transport-level session. In both of these cases,
>   even though the service is configured with
>   InstanceContextMode.PerSession and the contract with
>   SessionMode.Allowed, the service will behave as a per-call service,
>   and the calls to Dispose() are asynchronous; that is, the client is
>   not blocked after the call while WCF disposes of the instance.
>
> However, if you use the WSHttpBinding with security (its default
>   configuration) or with reliable messaging, or the NetTcpBinding, or
>   the NetNamedPipeBinding, then the service will behave as a per-session
>   service.

And here's a [list of system provided bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730879.aspx) along with some of their characteristics.

Comment: Hi, if web sites can manage sessions by using session id (in cookies) over connection-less HTTP, why can't WCF do it?

Answer (score 3):

`basicHttpBinding` does **not** support sessions - you can see a pretty good [overview of the binding features on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731092.aspx) (scroll down a little for the **Binding Features** section)