# Why WCF doesn't maintain session in basicHTTP Binding

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Wcf basicHttpBinding support PerSession?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330030/does-wcf-basichttpbinding-support-persession)

How come WCF doesn't support session for basicHTTPBinding since HTTP is stateless, but support session for wsHTTPBinding? (I know ReliableSession or Security should be enabled for wsHTTPBinding for PerSession to work), but still, how does it work? Can anyone please explain?