# Calling two methods of the same instance is triggering the Dispose method in WCF

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, c#-4.0

I am facing a weird situation.
I may have a less of understanding on it and I need some clarification.

I doing some printing stuff using WCF.
Following is the smallest as possible code snippet to presente my issue.

**WCF Service**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPrintLabelService
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool Generate(string templateFullFilename, Dictionary<string, string> textFields, Dictionary<string, string> imageFields);

    [OperationContract]
    bool Print(string printerName);
}

public class PrintLabelService : IPrintLabelService, IDisposable
{
    private WordWrapper _wordWrapper;

    public PrintLabelService()
    {
        _wordWrapper = new WordWrapper();
    }
    public bool Generate(string templateFullFilename, Dictionary<string, string> textFields, Dictionary<string, string> imageFields)
    {            
        return _wordWrapper.Generate(textFields, imageFields);            
    }
    public bool Print(string printerName)
    {
        return _wordWrapper.PrintDocument(printerName);                
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_wordWrapper != null)
        {
            _wordWrapper.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**Unit Test**

```
public void PrintLabelTestMethod()
{
    ILabel label = null;
    try
    {
        //some stuff
        // ...

        // Act
        label.Generate();            
        label.Print(printerName);    
    }
    finally
    {
        label.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**Label Class**

```
class Label : ILabel
{
    private readonly PrintLabelServiceClient _service;
    private bool _disposed = false;

    public Label(string templateFullFileName)
    {
        _service = new PrintLabelServiceClient();
    }
    public bool Generate()
    {   
        return _service.Generate(TemplateFullFileName, textFields, imageFields);
    }        
    public bool Print(string printerName)
    {
        return _service.Print(printer.Name);
    }         
}
```

When calling (Unit Test part)

```
label.Generate();
```

and then

```
label.Print(printerName);
```

the dispose method in the service is called twice (for each one of the above calls). And then the _wordWrapper is being reinitialized which is damaging its state.

Why the dispose is called for each one of the calls and how can I prevent Dispose to be called twice?

Comment: What binding do you use? `basicHttpBinding`?

Comment: yes, this is the one I am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your use case, you need to have the service use `InstanceContextMode.PerSession`. This, it seems, is not supported when using `basicHttpBinding` (see for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7330467/1429080)).

Since you are using `basicHttpBinding`, the service will therefore use `InstanceContextMode.PerCall`. This means that a new instance of `PrintLabelService` will be created for every incoming call to the service. And of course the new instance created for the `label.Print(printerName);` call will not see the local variable `_wordWrapper` from the instance that was used for the `label.Generate();` call.

In order to get this to work you need to switch to using a different binding that supports `InstanceContextMode.PerSession`. A `wsHttpBinding` maybe?

Comment: Actually it works very fine with basicHttpBinding. Thanks

Comment: It does? Interesting... Anyway, if it works - good for you! :-)