# Default InstanceContextMode in WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, c#-4.0, servicebehavior

In WCF, if we don't specify the InstanceContextMode of the ServiceBehaviour specifically, what is the default mode of the following?

1. PerCall
2. PerSession
3. Single

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the default instance context mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711361/what-is-the-default-instance-context-mode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode.aspx) on it talks about default value is `PerSession`. But I believe it also depends upon the binding used (does binding support sessions), like basichttpbinding uses `PerCall`

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that the default Instancing mode is `PerSession`

Provided:

- The Session Type you are using supports sessions
- See [Binding type session support] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/system-provided-bindings).
- If the channel does not create a session the behavior is as if it were `PerCall`.
- The Service contract allows sessions - default is "Allowed"

Here is a Microsoft provided sample with the default imperatively configured in the code.
[Default behavior sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/default-service-behavior)

```
[ServiceBehavior(  
AutomaticSessionShutdown=true,  
ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Single,  
InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerSession,  
IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=false,  
UseSynchronizationContext=true,  
ValidateMustUnderstand=true)]
public class CalculatorService : ICalculator { ... }
```

I found reading about session in this Microsoft article ( [Using Sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/using-sessions) ) particularly enlightening in understanding how Sessions is opened and closed and how this relates to Instancing and Concurrency.

By default the WCF client will create a new session, which will create a server instance, all calls for the duration of the session is called a conversation and is served by a single instance (Instancing) of the server with a single thread (Concurrency) dedicated to that session/client/conversation.

> If you use the default instancing behavior in WCF, all calls between a WCF client object are handled by the same service instance. Therefore, at the application level, you can think of a session as enabling application behavior similar to local call behavior. For example, when you create a local object:
>
> A constructor is called.
>
> All subsequent calls made to the WCF client object reference are processed by the same object instance.
>
> A destructor is called when the object reference is destroyed.
>
> Sessions enable a similar behavior between clients and services as long as the default service instance behavior is used.

Hope this helps someone as it took me a while to find the answer.