# What is the default instance context mode when using custom binding with httpTransport?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I need to know the default instance context mode when using custom binding with httpTransport.

I know that this question has been previously asked:

[What is the default instance context mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711361/what-is-the-default-instance-context-mode)

and it is stated that this depends on the config:

http://suntsu.ch/serendipity/index.php?/archives/191-What-is-the-default-for-WCF-if-InstanceContextMode-is-not-set-explicit.html

For my case, we are using custom binding with http transport :

```
     <customBinding>
        <binding name="customBinding" closeTimeout="00:03:00" openTimeout="00:03:00" receiveTimeout="00:03:00" sendTimeout="00:03:00">
          <binaryMessageEncoding compressionFormat="GZip">
            <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxDepth="32" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          </binaryMessageEncoding>
          <httpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
```

I guess our instance context mode is per call under this circumstances but I could not be sure... Could you please comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the answer myself. It is per call. I made a load test on the service and observed the service instance counter via perfmon. The service was hosted on a server with 2 processors. After applying the load, I saw that the number of instances initially increased consistently and then stuck at 32 (16*2). I was using default throttling setting and this is what it writes in "Programming WCF" book by Juval Lowy:

> With a per call service the number of instances is actually the same
>   as the number of concurrent calls

and the default value of maximum number of concurrent calls is :

> The default value is 16 times the processor (or cores) count.

I guess this proves that my configuration (custom binding with httpTransport) is making the service operate in per call mode.