# WCF Service Dispose the Server side Resources

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have the following service:

```cs
[ServiceContract]
interface IUsersService {
    [OperationContract]
    void CreateUser(UserDTO user)
}

public class UsersService : IUserService, IDisposable{
    IRepository<User> _userStore;

    UsersService(IRepository<User> userStore){
        _userStore = userStore;
    }

    public void CreateUser(UserDTO user){
        User newUser = user.ToEntity();
        _userStore.Add(newUser);
        _userStore.CommitChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose(){
        _userStore.Dispose();
    }
}
```

On the client side I have the following:

```cs
public class UsersController : Controller{
    private IUsersService service;

    // IUsersService is an ICommunicationObject
    public UsersController(IUsersService service){
        this.service = service;
    }

    public IActionResult CreateUser(UserDTO user){
        this.service.CreateUser(user);
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

How can I force the dispose method be called on the server side after doing everything I needed to do?

Alternatively, I haven't been able to figure out how to configure the service so that the Dispose method on the server side implementation of the service is called on a per-session basis (I need to dispose the db connection that comes in that IRepository instance). I have read about it but haven't been able to properly have it called.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Where is WCF service involved here ?  What do you want to dispose ?  The client object which calls service or the server side repositories or the controller object ?

Comment: @ManojChoudhari It could potentially be in a different server. Like it says in the question itself, I need to dispose of a db connection and potentially other resources. I did not understand your last question

Comment: Wcf will automatically call dispose method. If your  session mode is persession, it will be called when client proxy is closed.You could write console.writeline in your dispose method  and close your client  proxy to  have a test.You could also  expose a method to client to let client dispose the resource manually.

Comment: @AckelryXu Thanks for your reply. I have a breakpoint set there, it is not per-session currently, how does it behave by default? as a Singleton?

Comment: Default mode is persession. I'm not sure why you are not per-session. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711361/what-is-the-default-instance-context-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711361/what-is-the-default-instance-context-mode). Maybe you could set it explicitly.If it doesn't work, please also set  SessionMode to SessionMode.Required

Comment: Calling your `Dispose()` method at the end of your `CreateUser` method does not work?