# Should I implement IDisposable on a WCF Service?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service which has the following service behaviour attribute

```
  [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = 
  ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant)]
```

I have read online that WCF will call the Dispose method on a WCF service that implements IDisposable. However searching online for this topic doesn't reveal much and I haven't found anything in the Microsoft documentation that explicitly says you must implement IDisposable for a WCF service.

Given the InstanceContextMode I am assuming that any objects my service creates will be removed when a session ends. Reading this answer here [What is the default Instance Context Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50921227/593612) makes me think I could be 'lazy' and let WCF handle all the tidying up and dispose.

Am I correct in this assumption?

Comment: You implement `IDisposable` because you need to close and clean up resources like database connections, not to enable garbage collection. GC always works. Does your service use anything that needs closing or cleaning up at the end? Long-lived connections? Buffers from a buffer pool? Is there any explicit action it needs to take when a session ends?

Comment: This service does not have any database connections.

Comment: What *does* it do? In any case, the answer is no, the assumption is wrong because `IDisposable` has nothing to do with instancing behavior. You can avoid it if you don't need to clean up anything.

Comment: The service does create an instance of an object, that it uses to get and find information (but that doesn't go outside the system). I could implement IDisposable to be tidy but I could also leave it and rely on the GC eventually tidying up after me. After all if a WCF client stops making requests then the session will end. When a WCF client starts again then a new session is created.

Comment: Managed objects will be collected when the GC runs. It will detect that both the service and the object it holds are orphans and collect them. `Dispose()` is mainly used for unmanaged resources (database connections for example) or resources you want to release as soon as possible, even if they're managed. The GC will collect an open file stream for example but until it does, the file will remain locked.

Comment: That's what I thought.

Comment: Does the *other* object have a `Dispose()`? If it does, you probably need to implement IDisposable and forward the `Dispose()` call to that object

Comment: No the 'other' object does not.

Comment: In that case you can't do anything except `null` the field. The GC would collect both objects even if you didn't.